# Calculate transform y-scale property as the function of elapsed time

Tags: javascript, html, animation, math, transformation

I have a container that is expanded and collapsed on click of chevron icon. The code to collapse/expand the container is in the function `transformAnimation`. The code of `transformAnimation` is similar to the [code on MDN web docs for `requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#examples). The code to animate (scale) the container has been developed on the guidelines of [this article on Building performant expand & collapse animations on Chrome Developers website](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/performant-expand-and-collapse/#good-animating-scales).

I am not able to figure out how to calculate `yScale` value (which is nothing but y scale values for collapse/expand animation) as a function of the time elapsed since the start of the animation.

To elaborate what I mean, let's assume that the container is in expanded state. In this state the `scaleY` value of the container is 6. Now when user clicks on the toggle button, in the `transformAnimation` function for each animation frame, i.e, execution of the `requestAnimationFrame` callback `step` function, the value of `scaleY` should decrease from 6 (the expanded state) to 1 (the collapsed state) in the exact duration that I want the animation to run for.

In the present state, the code to calculate `yScale` is not working as expected.

```js
const dragExpandableContainer = document.querySelector('.drag-expandable-container');
const dragExpandableContents = document.querySelector('.drag-expandable__contents');
const resizeableControlEl = document.querySelector('.drag-expandable__resize-control');
const content = document.querySelector(`.content`);
const toggleEl = document.querySelector(`.toggle`);

const collapsedHeight = calculateCollapsedHeight();

/* This height is used as the basis for calculating all the scales for the component.
 * It acts as proxy for collapsed state.
 */
dragExpandableContainer.style.height = `${collapsedHeight}px`;

// Apply iniial transform to expand
dragExpandableContainer.style.transformOrigin = 'bottom left';
dragExpandableContainer.style.transform = `scale(1, 10)`;

// Apply iniial reverse transform on the contents 
dragExpandableContents.style.transformOrigin = 'bottom left';
dragExpandableContents.style.transform = `scale(1, calc(1/10))`;

let isOpen = true;

const togglePopup = () => {
  if (isOpen) {
    collapsedAnimation();
    toggleEl.classList.remove('toggle-open');
    isOpen = false;
  } else {
    expandAnimation();
    toggleEl.classList.add('toggle-open');
    isOpen = true
  };
};

function calculateCollapsedHeight() {
  const collapsedHeight = content.offsetHeight + resizeableControlEl.offsetHeight;
  return collapsedHeight;
}

const calculateCollapsedScale = function() {
  const collapsedHeight = calculateCollapsedHeight();
  const expandedHeight = dragExpandableContainer.getBoundingClientRect().height;

  return {
    /* Since we are not dealing with scaling on X axis, we keep it 1.
     * It can be inverse to if required */
    x: 1,
    y: expandedHeight / collapsedHeight,
  };
};

const calculateExpandScale = function() {
  const collapsedHeight = calculateCollapsedHeight();
  const expandedHeight = 100;

  return {
    x: 1,
    y: expandedHeight / collapsedHeight,
  };
};

function expandAnimation() {
  const {
    x,
    y
  } = calculateExpandScale();

  transformAnimation('expand', {
    x,
    y
  });
}

function collapsedAnimation() {
  const {
    x,
    y
  } = calculateCollapsedScale();

  transformAnimation('collapse', {
    x,
    y
  });
}

function transformAnimation(animationType, scale) {
  let start, previousTimeStamp;
  let done = false;

  function step(timestamp) {
    if (start === undefined) {
      start = timestamp;
    }
    const elapsed = timestamp - start;

    if (previousTimeStamp !== timestamp) {
      const count = Math.min(0.1 * elapsed, 200);
      //console.log('count', count);
      let yScale;
      
      if (animationType === 'expand') {
        yScale = (scale.y / 100) * count;
      } else yScale = scale.y - (scale.y / 100) * count;
      //console.log('yScale', yScale);
      if (yScale < 1) yScale = 1;
      
      dragExpandableContainer.style.transformOrigin = 'bottom left';
      dragExpandableContainer.style.transform = `scale(${scale.x}, ${yScale})`;

      const inverseXScale = 1;
      const inverseYScale = 1 / yScale;
      
      dragExpandableContents.style.transformOrigin = 'bottom left';
      dragExpandableContents.style.transform = `scale(${inverseXScale}, ${inverseYScale})`;

      if (count === 200) done = true;

      //console.log('elapsed', elapsed);
      if (elapsed < 1000) {
        // Stop the animation after 2 seconds
        previousTimeStamp = timestamp;
        if (!done) requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

```css
.drag-expandable-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f7f7;
}

.drag-expandable__contents {
  height: 0;
}

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}

.toggle-open {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.drag-expandable__resize-control {
  background-color: #e7eeef;
}

.burger-icon {
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

.burger-icon__line {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #738F93;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.drag-expandable__resize-control:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid #4caf50;
  cursor: ns-resize;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="drag-expandable-container">
    <div class="drag-expandable__contents">
      <div class="drag-expandable__resize-control">
        <div class="burger-icon">
          <div class="burger-icon__line"></div>
          <div class="burger-icon__line"></div>
          <div class="burger-icon__line"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" />
      <div>
        <div class="toggle toggle-open" onclick="togglePopup()">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.1.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M416 352c-8.188 0-16.38-3.125-22.62-9.375L224 173.3l-169.4 169.4c-12.5 12.5-32.75 12.5-45.25 0s-12.5-32.75 0-45.25l192-192c12.5-12.5 32.75-12.5 45.25 0l192 192c12.5 12.5 12.5 32.75 0 45.25C432.4 348.9 424.2 352 416 352z"/></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Generally speaking, pasting a wall of (non-related) code won't get you answers easily. Try isolating the problem and dramatically reduce the code in your question and people will more likely try to help you out.

Comment: @VictoriaStudio Is the Cognitive Complexity difficult or is the question not clear?

Comment: It's far too much code, as stated before.

Comment: @VictoriaStudios Its MRE. Suggest edits that you think will help reduce the code.